# Getting keyboard inputs in Octave using the input() function

Tags: parsing, input, octave

I'm currently using Octave in Windows through Xoctave and I'm having the following problem.

I attempted to run a script that starts with

```
activity = input("What would you like to do? ");
```

When I called this script in the console, it prints out

```
What would you like to do?
```

When I key in a number and press enter, it returns:

```
What would you like to do? 1

error: `What' undefined near line 4 column 1

>>
```

It seems as if the console is trying to parse the output of the previous command (i.e.,  trying to parse the whole line, including the prompt text).

To get a clearer picture of what I'm trying to say, just save a script with only the line:

```
m = input('Enter m: ');
```

then try to run that script in Xoctave. I believe you'll get the same error too.

I believe this has to do with changing the default parsing behavior, but I'm not sure how.

@Bart_Kiers
I think you misunderstand =\ 
When I do what you just prescribed, it stores:
activity = What would you like to do? 1
I want it to just store activity=1
the only way I've found to do this is to do:
    activity1=input("Pick 1 or 0");
    activity2=strrep(activity,"Pick 1 or 0 ",""); 
    activity=str2num(activity2)

To which it will output:
    activity=1

To clarify the issue, it creates a similar, yet significantly more frustrating problem using the menu function. 
if i do this:

```
number=menu("What's your favorite number?",1,2,3,4,5);
```

it prompts:

```
[ 1] 1
[ 2] 2
[ 3] 3
[ 4] 4
[ 5] 5

pick a number, any number:
```

I key in 3 and press enter and it returns: "error: input invalid or out of range" because it is trying to parse the entire line, including the prompt! =[ help!

Also, I'm using Xoctave to interface with the Octave command line in Windows.
Not sure if this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't see any reason why `input()` doesn't work. Did you try it using a standard Octave console, which works for me (I'm on a Mac, and don't have access to Xoctave)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your error, but you might try:

```
m = input("Enter m: \n");
```

New line won't work with menu though.